# How does Go select decide to run into the default branch?

Tags: go

I have a program in which I have 256 goroutines generating test data and sending them to a channel.

In the consuming part of the program, I set up a select like this:

```
select {
case c := <-theChan:
    // Do some stuff with c
default:
    //
}
```

What surprise me is that while the 256 goroutines keep sending items to the channel and the processing of the items take time? The program runs into the `default` branch several times.

I wonder how does the `select` statement decide that `theChan` is empty and run into `default`.

Comment: Select chooses the 'default' case if it cannot receive from the channel, or the channel is nil.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements (Rule of thumb: Always consult the language spec first. Contrary to other languages, Go's spec is understandable.)

Comment: If the spec is too technical, there's an entire page of the tour dedicated to default in select: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/6

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scheduler, but between the time you consume a value from the channel and the time another goroutine gets execution time allocated by the scheduler (which would add a value in the channel), the main goroutine may have enough time to run the case and go back to the `select` statement before a value is added to the channel, it would then run the `default` case.

You could reduce this by using a buffered channel.